# Using ActionBuilder together with securesocial SecuredAction

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I am using play 2.2.1 with securesocial and many of my actions are authenticated using the `SecuredAction` provided by securesocial.

Now I would like to create an `ActionBuilder` for a specific type of request, like the ItemAction in the documentation.

I try to do something like this

```
  /**
   * ActionBuilder for use with actions that use Item objects.
   */
  def ItemAction() = new ActionBuilder[RequestWithItem] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: SecuredRequest[A], block: (RequestWithItem[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
      val futureItem = itemsCollection.
        find(Json.obj("identityId" -> request.user.identityId)).one[Item]
      futureItem.flatMap { maybeItem =>
        maybeItem match {
          case Some(item) => {
            block(new RequestWithItem(item, request))
          }
          case _ => Future(BadRequest("could not get a item for this user."))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and I get this compile error

```
 object creation impossible, since method invokeBlock in trait ActionBuilder of type [A](request: play.api.mvc.Request[A], block: models.RequestWithitem[A] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult] is not defined
```

I understand that invokeBlock is supposed to take a `play.api.mvc.Request[A]` instead of a `securesocial.core.SecuredRequest[A]`, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to compose ItemAction with SecuredAction (by way of SecureSocial), this would be one approach:

```
case class Item(id: Long) // replace with your real world item

def SecuredItemAction(f: => Item => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
  SecuredAction { implicit request =>
  val item = Some(new Item(7)) // replace with your real world item fetch
  item.map { item =>
    f(item)(request)
  }.getOrElse(NotFound)
}
```

And then you can use it in the following way:

```
def index = SecuredItemAction { item =>
  implicit request =>
    Ok(item.id.toString)
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get SecuredItemAction as an Action object?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do. Could you update your question with how you would like to use your Action?

Comment: I'm trying to create something that I can re-use with different body parsers for different actions and that will also work with async results.

Comment: @yzernik Did you come up with something that can use different body parsers?